# Keeping height of div when layering divs with relative/absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to layer some divs using relative/absolute positioning. The problem I can't seem to fix is the div below the wrapper div.

Check out this [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ymdahi/3qypLpsd/) to see what I mean.

Notice the position of the div.more-stuff. I would like that div to display underneath div#wrap.

```
#wrap {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
.node-content {
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
left: 5%;
width: 80%;
background: rgba(236, 240, 241, 1.0);
padding: 5%;
}
.bg-img img {
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
background: rgba(192, 57, 43, 1.0);
}
.more-stuff {
}
```

Comment: Define "underneath". Do you mean layering these two divs on top of each other, as in three dimensional space, or do you mean placing these divs on top of each other in two dimensional space, so they don't overlap each other? Because these two cases are completely different and require major reworks to your code both. 3D: https://jsfiddle.net/jdqv604e/ 2D: https://jsfiddle.net/rhc5cpuc/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 3D or 2D... the effect I'm looking for is similar to this layout: http://demo.themebrain.com/tb_corpal/. Notice how the main content region is positioned over the slider.

Comment: Negative margin top by percentage? That's basic.

Comment: negative margin over an image will not will work as the background color of the overlaying div will not show over the image. The effect looks easy (negative margin, etc.), but the *best* way to do it is using relative/absolute positioning in concert. The problem with using positioning to achieve this is that any div outside of the wrapping div will not be aware of the height of the absolute positioned div and thereby display behind the content. In fact, give the negative margin approach a try and you'll find the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was trying to use the relative/absolute positioning in concert to float one div above the other. This seems to be the wrong way - the right way I found on [Smashing Mag](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/):

Add `position: relative;` to the div that I want to position over the cover image div did the trick. Check out the final [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ymdahi/3qypLpsd/).

Here's the code snippet to run as well:

```css
body { background: rgba(46, 204, 113,1.0) }

  #main-container { width: 80%; max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; }

  .cover-photo { max-height:  520px; overflow:  hidden; }
  .cover-photo img { width: 100%; height: auto; background: rgba(192, 57, 43,1.0); }
  
  .content-region { 
    position: relative; /* add position: relative to floating region, but do not add position: absolute to wrapping div. */
    width: 80%;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: -215px auto 25px;
    background: rgba(236, 240, 241,1.0);
  }

  .left-col { float: left; width: 30%; }
  .right-col { float: right; width: 69%; }

  .below-content { padding: 50px; background: #000; color: #fff; }
  
  .clearfix:after {
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   font-size: 0;
   content: " ";
   clear: both;
   height: 0;
   }
  .clearfix { display: inline-block; }
  /* start commented backslash hack \*/
  * html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
  .clearfix { display: block; }
  /* close commented backslash hack */
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  
  <div class="cover-photo">
 <img src="http://static.pexels.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/iphone-macbook-air-man-156-825x550.jpg">
  </div>
  
  <div class="content-region clearfix">
    
    <div class="left-col">
      <h1>The title of the page</h1>
      <p>Porttitor eros nesciunt, fugiat? Cupidatat, enim eligendi! Tempor commodi risus facilisi conubia? Pulvinar deleniti etiam nostrud cras magni bibendum hendrerit dictumst imperdiet blandit possimus porttitor eiusmod lorem feugiat dolor cillum! Ratione mattis, maecenas! Perspiciatis.</p>
      <h2>The title of the page</h2>
      <p>Doloremque! Phasellus faucibus! Repellat iure eleifend ullam neque debitis culpa, condimentum et aute voluptatibus odio eiusmod similique tempora facere doloribus itaque. Dictumst neque interdum. Nonummy</p>
    </div><!-- left-col -->
       
    <div class="right-col">
      <h1>Main content column</h1>
      <p>Porttitor eros nesciunt, fugiat? Cupidatat, enim eligendi! Tempor commodi risus facilisi conubia? Pulvinar deleniti etiam nostrud cras magni bibendum hendrerit dictumst imperdiet blandit possimus porttitor eiusmod lorem feugiat dolor cillum! Ratione mattis, maecenas! Perspiciatis. Lacinia erat condimentum proin hymenaeos quisque? Voluptatibus varius, minima, dolorem! Quasi, class? Rhoncus proin porro hymenaeos hymenaeos commodi sociis repudiandae vel unde voluptates similique voluptatum natus, pariatur non pretium nascetur eaque, fames elementum similique rem voluptate, laboriosam corrupti atque doloribus impedit pulvinar neque nibh dictumst ab! Iusto, proin voluptatibus doloremque, molestie cubilia eaque officiis tincidunt hac cubilia explicabo architecto dignissim officiis, sapien, maiores tristique. Nesciunt, arcu.</p>
      <p>Porttitor eros nesciunt, fugiat? Cupidatat, enim eligendi! Tempor commodi risus facilisi conubia? Pulvinar deleniti etiam nostrud cras magni bibendum hendrerit dictumst imperdiet blandit possimus porttitor eiusmod lorem feugiat dolor cillum! Ratione mattis, maecenas! Perspiciatis. Lacinia erat condimentum proin hymenaeos quisque? Voluptatibus varius, minima, dolorem! Quasi, class? Rhoncus proin porro hymenaeos hymenaeos commodi sociis repudiandae vel unde voluptates similique voluptatum natus, pariatur non pretium nascetur eaque, fames elementum similique rem voluptate, laboriosam corrupti atque doloribus impedit pulvinar neque nibh dictumst ab! Iusto, proin voluptatibus doloremque, molestie cubilia eaque officiis tincidunt hac cubilia explicabo architecto dignissim officiis, sapien, maiores tristique. Nesciunt, arcu.</p>
      <p>Porttitor eros nesciunt, fugiat? Cupidatat, enim eligendi! Tempor commodi risus facilisi conubia? Pulvinar deleniti etiam nostrud cras magni bibendum hendrerit dictumst imperdiet blandit possimus porttitor eiusmod lorem feugiat dolor cillum! Ratione mattis, maecenas! Perspiciatis. Lacinia erat condimentum proin hymenaeos quisque? Voluptatibus varius, minima, dolorem! Quasi, class? Rhoncus proin porro hymenaeos hymenaeos commodi sociis repudiandae vel unde voluptates similique voluptatum natus, pariatur non pretium nascetur eaque, fames elementum similique rem voluptate, laboriosam corrupti atque doloribus impedit pulvinar neque nibh dictumst ab! Iusto, proin voluptatibus doloremque, molestie cubilia eaque officiis tincidunt hac cubilia explicabo architecto dignissim officiis, sapien, maiores tristique. Nesciunt, arcu.</p>
      <p>Porttitor eros nesciunt, fugiat? Cupidatat, enim eligendi! Tempor commodi risus facilisi conubia? Pulvinar deleniti etiam nostrud cras magni bibendum hendrerit dictumst imperdiet blandit possimus porttitor eiusmod lorem feugiat dolor cillum! Ratione mattis, maecenas! Perspiciatis. Lacinia erat condimentum proin hymenaeos quisque? Voluptatibus varius, minima, dolorem! Quasi, class? Rhoncus proin porro hymenaeos hymenaeos commodi sociis repudiandae vel unde voluptates similique voluptatum natus, pariatur non pretium nascetur eaque, fames elementum similique rem voluptate, laboriosam corrupti atque doloribus impedit pulvinar neque nibh dictumst ab! Iusto, proin voluptatibus doloremque, molestie cubilia eaque officiis tincidunt hac cubilia explicabo architecto dignissim officiis, sapien, maiores tristique. Nesciunt, arcu.</p>
    </div><!-- right-col -->
  
  </div> <!-- content-region -->
  
  <div class="below-content">
        <h1>Other things below content</h1>
        <p>Porttitor eros nesciunt, fugiat? Cupidatat, enim eligendi! Tempor commodi risus facilisi conubia? Pulvinar deleniti etiam nostrud cras magni bibendum hendrerit dictumst imperdiet blandit possimus porttitor eiusmod lorem feugiat dolor cillum! Ratione mattis, maecenas! Perspiciatis. Lacinia erat condimentum proin hymenaeos quisque? Voluptatibus varius, minima, dolorem! Quasi, class? Rhoncus proin porro hymenaeos hymenaeos commodi sociis repudiandae vel unde voluptates similique voluptatum natus, pariatur non pretium nascetur eaque, fames elementum similique rem voluptate, laboriosam corrupti atque doloribus impedit pulvinar neque nibh dictumst ab! Iusto, proin voluptatibus doloremque, molestie cubilia eaque officiis tincidunt hac cubilia explicabo architecto dignissim officiis, sapien, maiores tristique. Nesciunt, arcu.</p>
  </div><!-- below-content -->
  
</div><!-- #main-container -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did little bit changes in CSS as you can see in the code below and the fiddle is :

### [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m9yecrct/)

CSS

```
body {
    background: rgba(46, 204, 113, 1.0)
}
#main-container {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    
}
.node-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 80%;
    background: rgba(236, 240, 241, 1.0);
    padding: 5%;
    
}
.bg-img img {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.more-stuff{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(192, 57, 43, 1.0);
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: sorry, this is not the effect I was looking for.

Comment: I really have no idea what's wrong in that ... I thought you put red color box to make that more-stuff fits in it or else it was so easy to make any div and put text.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need something ??

```
.more-stuff {
    position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ymdahi/3qypLpsd/embedded/result/